# Lenovo Thinkpad T400 not getting past boot screen

Tags: usb, display, thinkpad, splash

so as the title suggests I have got a Lenovo T400 from a friend who wants me to fix it for them. It does not get past the splash screen and whenever I leave it on for about 5 seconds or so it just turns off. Once I got it to the page which says that the battery is critically low but have not been able to get it past the splash screen since.

People have suggested that one of the USB ports got shorted out by carelessly pulling it out etc. I did have a damaged port but straightening them out and unsporting them did nothing. I have also tried resetting the CMOS which did nothing either.

All answers are appreciated

Comment: Based on what you describe. It sounds like its time for a new laptop.  The behavior indicates a hardware failure.

Comment: What operating system are you trying to boot? Couldn't it be that the HDD or OS is damaged hence not being able to load the bootloader. Could you try for example a linux live cd?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it might be but I might be able to breath a tiny bit of life into this, so I will keep on trying. If it is still broken by tonight then it is going in the trash.

Comment: @ap0 I will try that, I'm pretty surprised that I didn't think of that! But my OS is windows 7. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ap0 I just tried the hard drive on a different laptop and it seems to boot up fine.

Comment: @AlexMaurerbriggs: Try a LiveCD as suggested, and also with the battery removed and charger connected.

Comment: Well, I fixed it. :) it was the thermal paste and the usb. There is a common problem with Lenovo laptops where if the USB pins are touching then they try to boot from the non existent usb. Also the thermal paste turned into a clay type thing which caused it to turn off all the time.